# Displaying a slideshow in the background of a SharePoint homepage [2016]

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, script-webpart, homepage

I would like to know if it is possible to integrate html/css code to implement a slideshow as a wallpaper on the home page of a SharePoint site. This slideshow must appear in the background in relation to the titles and web part of the page.

I tried to introduce a web part script editor. The code is recognized but I cannot save it (the "insert" button is quickly hidden by the slideshow preview). I also tried to introduce a content editor web part. This also works but the slideshow goes over the page titles and menus generated by SharePoint.

For me it's a problem configuring the "masterpage" or the `Accuail.aspx` page. I have SharePoint designer but I am a little limited in coding to provide this functionality.

Thanks.

Comment: It is not recommended to modify master page in SharePoint Server...